# Java+Cucumber: get the current tag/abverb being executed

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumber-java

I am trying to print the current step being executed in Cucumber. I am using a custom formatter to print the step definition. However, I also want to print the current adverb (Given, When, Then, And...) that is being executed. I might be missing something as well, is it possible in Cucumber? Here is my code:

Formatter:

```
public class MyCucumberFormatter implements ConcurrentEventListener {

    @Override
    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, runStartedHandler);
    }

    private EventHandler<TestStepStarted> runStartedHandler = new EventHandler<TestStepStarted>() {
        @Override
        public void receive(TestStepStarted event) {
            startReport(event);
        }
    };

    private void startReport(TestStepStarted event) {
        if (!(event.testStep instanceof PickleStepTestStep)) {
            return;
        }
        PickleStepTestStep testStep = (PickleStepTestStep) event.testStep;
        log("Step: " + testStep.getStepText());
    }
}
```

Example scenario:

```
Scenario: Test user life cycle: create user, activate and delete
  Given A valid admin logs in
  When Admin creates new user
  And User is activated
  Then User should successfully login
```

Right now, it prints as:

```
    A valid admin logs in
    Admin creates new user
    User is activated
    User should successfully login
```

I want it to print as:

> **Given** A valid admin logs in
>       **When** Admin creates new user
>       **And** User is activated
>       **Then** User should successfully login

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/56165423/3355860

Comment: Why not use one of the built in formatters?

Comment: @Marit I am not able to use the built in formatters as I want to print all the log statements for the current step. Is it possible in built in formatters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in v4.x yet but you can do this in v5.0.0-RC1 by going through `pickleStepTestStep.getStep().getKeyWord()`

Comment: I am also trying to figure out if there is a way to add my current Info logs to the current step being executed. Is this possible in the newer version as well?

Comment: Most logging frameworks will let you attach a custom appender. You can probably attach one in the plugin. Beware of parallel execution though.