# How to get scenario name from a scenario outline in cypress gherkin setup?

Tags: cucumber, cypress, gherkin

Suppose I have a test case like -

```
Scenario: Scenario to verify Title Matched 

  When Navigate to the App "Facebook"

  Then verify the "TitleName" Field
```

How could I get the scenario name from the step definition methods corresponding to "  When Navigate to the App Facebook" and "Then verify the "TitleName" Field"

Step definitions methods are -

```
When('Navigate to the App {string} for demo',(AppURL:string)=>{

    if(AppURL=="FaceBook"){

    }

});

Then('verify the Title of the page for demo',()=>

 {    
        SampleAPPUI.verfiyTitledemo('');

});
```

**Note**: I am using cypres-cucumber with typescript

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this in a Java-Selenium-Gherkin test suite. It may not be the solution you need, but it will give you some direction about how to get the values:

```
@BeforeStep
public void doSomethingBeforeStep(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
    testScenario = scenario.getName().toString();
    scenarioObj = scenario;
    Field f = scenario.getClass().getDeclaredField("testCase");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    TestCase r = (TestCase) f.get(scenario);

    List<PickleStepTestStep> stepDefs = r.getTestSteps()
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> x instanceof PickleStepTestStep)
            .map(x -> (PickleStepTestStep) x)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    PickleStepTestStep currentStepDef = stepDefs.get(currentStepIndex);
    testCase = currentStepDef.getStepText();
}
```

Also, see [here](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664422/in-cucumber-is-it-possible-to-programmatically-get-the-current-step-being-execu)

Comment: I am not getting a way to retrieve object of Scenario in cypress cucumber using typescript.

Comment: @HardikRana so i'm assuming there is no correlation between Java Cucumber and Typecscript Cucumber then.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me, though I'm not using TS, the logic behind it should give you a good starting point:

```
    function getScenarioName(){
    const _onRunnableRun = Cypress.runner.onRunnableRun
    Cypress.runner.onRunnableRun = function (runnableRun, runnable, args) {
      const r = runnable
      const isHook = r.type === 'hook'
      const isAfterAllHook = isHook && r.hookName.match(/after all/)
      const isBeforeHook = isHook && r.hookName.match(/before each/)
      const test = r.ctx.currentTest || r

      var testTitle = test.title //this is the test title

      const next = args[0]
      if (
        isHook &&
        r.ctx.currentTest &&
        r.ctx.currentTest.trueFn &&
        !isAfterAllHook
      ) {
        return next.call(this)
      }
      const onNext = function (err) {
        const fail = function () {
          return next.call(this, err)
        }
        const noFail = function () {
          test.err = null
          return next.call(this)
        }
        if (err) {
          if (test._retries === -1) {
            test._retries = getDefaultRetries()
          }
          if (isBeforeHook && test._currentRetry < test._retries) {
            test.trueFn = test.fn
            test.fn = function () {
              throw err
            }
            return noFail()
          }
        }
        return fail()
      }
      args[0] = onNext
      return _onRunnableRun.apply(this, [runnableRun, runnable, args])
    }
}
```