# How to get scenario steps with cucumber Java?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I want before run cucumber scenarios get this scenario steps and i have a test result json file, i will add step of running scenario into this json file but now i can't get steps, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your StepDefinition class:

```
@BeforeStep
public void doSomethingBeforeStep(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
    testScenario = scenario.getName().toString();
    scenarioObj = scenario;
    Field f = scenario.getClass().getDeclaredField("testCase");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    TestCase r = (TestCase) f.get(scenario);

    List<PickleStepTestStep> stepDefs = r.getTestSteps()
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> x instanceof PickleStepTestStep)
            .map(x -> (PickleStepTestStep) x)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    PickleStepTestStep currentStepDef = stepDefs.get(currentStepIndex);
    testCase = currentStepDef.getStepText();
}

@AfterStep
public void doSomethingAfterStep(Scenario scenario) {
    currentStepDefIndex += 1;
}
```

Credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56906835/3355860) post. And the API [doc](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/).